# GitHub - Remove a indexed file from "Languages" on first page

Tags: github, indexing

How can I remove this indexed HTML page, that are a documentation to one of the external librarys I use on my GitHub blob?

I have tried alot of diffrent commands, but don't find a way to remove this file from the [GitHub Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) indexer...

Here are the "Languages" that are indexed on the startpage:
[[image] Languages on the startpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpmXI.png)

The file that I want to exclude:
[[image] HTML file that needs to be excluded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYp4c.png)

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
```

Code that I've tried to get it removed via ".attributes"-file in root-folder (the vendored, works... But not getting rid of this HTML-file... from the GitHub-Languages) :

```
### vendored:
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/* linguist-vendored

### documentations:
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/* linguist-documentation
```

and tried:

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/* -linguist-documentation
```

and this:

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/* linguist-documentation
```

and this:

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/* -linguist-documentation
```

and this:

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/* linguist-documentation
```

and this:

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/* -linguist-documentation
```

But I can't figure it out how to remove this file:

```
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
```

Please help me with the correct syntax to remove the file from being indexed as a Language in my GitHub repository, main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea and the right Linguist overrides (either will do the trick). The problem is your path matching isn't quite right.

From the [`.gitattributes` docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

> The rules by which the pattern matches paths are the same as in `.gitignore` files (see gitignore[5]), with a few exceptions:
> [...]

If we look in the [`.gitignore` docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (emphasis is mine):

> An asterisk "`*`" matches anything **except a slash**. The character "`?`" matches any one character except "`/`". The range notation, e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`, can be used to match one of the characters in a range. See fnmatch(3) and the FNM_PATHNAME flag for a more detailed description.
>
> Two consecutive asterisks ("`**`") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
> [...]
>
> - A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.

The files you're trying to ignore are in sub-directories of the paths you've specified so you need to either:

- use `TestProject/wwwroot/lib/** linguist-vendored` to recurse, or
- use `TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/* linguist-vendored` to limit to this directory.

We can demonstrate this without even using Linguist thanks to `git check-attr`:

```console
$ # Create a repo with just the one file
$ git init -q Test-Project
$ cd Test-Project
$ mkdir -p TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/
$ echo "<html>" > TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m 'Add file'
[main (root-commit) bed71b5] Add file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
$
$ # Add your initial override
$ git add -A && git commit -m 'attribs'
[main 7d0a0cf] attribs
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
$
$ # Check the attributes
$ git check-attr linguist-vendored TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html: linguist-vendored: unspecified
$ # So it doesn't have any effect.
$ # Now lets recurse
$ echo "TestProject/wwwroot/lib/** linguist-vendored" > .gitattributes
$ git add -A && git commit -m 'attribs'
[main 9007c34] attribs
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git check-attr linguist-vendored TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html: linguist-vendored: set
$ # Woohoo!!! It's work. 
$ # Lets be specific to the docs dir
$ echo "TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/* linguist-vendored" > .gitattributes
$ git add -A && git commit -m 'attribs'
[main a46f416] attribs
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git check-attr linguist-vendored TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html
TestProject/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-icons/docs/index.html: linguist-vendored: set
$ # Woohoo!!! It's worked too
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good troubleshooting from @lildude, shown that:

1. All the files was ignored correctly.
2. I had alot of CSHTML-files under my repository that was grouped as HTML+Razor (see this post on GitHub: [GitHub linguist discussion](https://github.com/github/linguist/discussions/5175#discussioncomment-318038) ) .
3. When I clicked the "HTML"-link on startpage under language, it took me to: https://github.com/pownas/Test-Project/search?l=html
4. But the startpage under language was telling me that I had around 40% html from the HTML+Razor search: https://github.com/pownas/Test-Project/search?l=HTML%2BRazor